# How to make ddos attack to my web application?

Tags: ddos, ip-restrictions, azure-ddos

Hi I have developed web application in angular 5 and hosted in azure cloud. I am trying to prevent ddos attach to my application. I have added below code in my web.config.

```
  <security>
      <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="NotFound">
        <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="10" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="2000"/>
        <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="10"/>
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
    </security>
```

Now I want to test my application by making concurrent calls to this application. I have two things here. Currently i have not deployed latest code to azure so above changes not there in my public site. I am trying to test in localhost by sending concurrent requests as `ping http://localhost:1148/ -t -l 65000` When i do this i get ping request could not find host error is coming. Can someone help me to make ddos attack? Also i tried to public site as above and same error is poping up. Can someone help me to make attack? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: where are you running ping command? on same machine where website is hosted?

Comment: Thank you. Yes same machine.

Comment: you cannot to ping to specific port number. Also remove http:// and use `localhost`